# python 2d contourf plot using 3d np array data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a problem here.

My data is a 3d shape of np array
(256, 256, 1) = (x coordinate, y coordinate, pressure value)
Now I would like to draw a contour plot using this np array.

But the problem is that the shape of my data does not fit into plt.contourf

Any idea on how to preprocess my data before feeding it to contourf?

Comment: `print((data[:,:,0]).shape)`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a singular value for each position [M,N], you can simply squeeze out that dimension and have it represented by a matrix of shape [M,N].

```
data = data.squeeze(2)
plt.contourf(data)
```

The squeezed and original array contain the exact same data, but are just represented slightly differently.